# How can a child backbone view get access to its parent view specific properties without passing whole 'this' as parent

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a backbone parent view

```
var ParentView = Backbone.View.extend({
  a : 'apple',
  b : 'boy',
  c : 'cat',
  changingA : function() {
     this.a = 'Ami'
   },
  createChild = function() {
      new ChildView({a : this.a});
   }
});
```

and a child view

```
var ChildView = Backbone.View.extend({
   intialize : function(args) {
     this.aa = args.a;
   },

   someOperation : function() {
      console.log(this.aa);  // this is not the current 'a' value of parent.
         //here i always get 'apple' even if i change the value of 'a' in parent
    }
});
```

How can i make sure this.aa in child always get the current available value in parent view.

what is the main reason behind that? I am passing 'reference' of 'a' to child view. So child view should always have the updated value from parent.  But why this do not happens??

**I also do not want to pass the whole 'this' parameter as parent to child**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create an object and share the reference between parent and child

```
var ParentView = Backbone.View.extend({
  obj: {
    a : 'apple',
    b : 'boy',
    c : 'cat'
  },
  changingA : function() {
     this.obj.a = 'Ami'
   },
  createChild = function() {
      new ChildView({obj : this.obj});
   }
});

var ChildView = Backbone.View.extend({
   intialize : function(args) {
     this.obj = args.obj;
   },

   someOperation : function() {
      console.log(this.obj.a);  // this is not the current 'a' value of parent.
         //here i always get 'Apple' even if i change the value of 'a' in parent
    }
});
```

But be careful, this object reference is also shared between instances of "ParentView", to bypass this problem, create the obj reference inside constructor.

Comment: i told in the question, i do not want to pass whole 'this' as parent to child.

Comment: i'll rewrite the answer then

Comment: Ok, this one works good,.. but what is the main reason behind failure of mine approach? I am passing 'reference' of 'a' to child view. So child view should always have the updated value from parent.  But why this do not happens??

Comment: You're passing the reference of a string and string, as well as java, is immutable, the moment you do this.obj.a = 'Ami', you're putting another reference into the parent. The child will still refer the old reference.